Why are errors missing from my custom validator?
I am using rjsf FormBuilder to make a form in a react application.
I'm trying to track down some strange error behavior, and along the way I tried adding some customValidate to examine errors.
What's got me confused first and foremost is: why doesn't my custom validator receive any errors?

I know there are errors somewhere, because errors show up in the UI.  Why are there no errors in the error arg of my custom validator?
See CodeSandbox for minimal example.
Thanks!
